# Parent triggering function defined in Child, React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

Good afternoon,

I have a react native project. I currently have 3 major UI components:

A **timeline** which consists of a user defined number of **channels**, which have a fluctuating number of **events** (Think gantt chart or audio editors). I want a button defined in the timeline to call a function defined in the child channel object, change some parameters as defined in the child function, and re-render.

UPDATED: I refactored the original code posted here to all be contained within a single class, but having similar issues. Refactored code:

```
class TIMELINE extends Component{
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      allEvents: [],
      allChannels:[],
    };
  }
  render() {
    return(
      <View>
          <Text style={styles.welcomeMessage}>Timeline</Text>
          <View name=CONATINER_VIEW>
          {
            this.state.allChannels.map((channel)=>{
              console.log(channel); //<<<<This is Printing proper info
              renderChannel(this, channel) //<<<< Renders nothing
            })
          }
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }

renderChannel = (timeline, channel) =>{
  return (
   <View style={[styles.container, styles.channelContainer, styles.channelWrapper]} name="ChannelWrapperViewThing">
      <View style={styles.verticleLine}></View>
      <Pressable  style={styles.eventLane} onPressIn={timeline.handlePressIn}  onPressOut={timeline.handlePressOut}>
      {//RenderEvents TBD}
      </Pressable>
    </View>
  )
}
```

This refactored code splits out the recursive display of channels and events into their own rendering functions. During the loop, I print out the stored channel datils to the console, and that print is working and printing the expected values, but nothing returned from renderChannel() is rendered, and if I inspect the wrapping view name=****CONATINER_VIEW****, has the correct number of children (depending on how many channels have been added) in the array, but they are all undefined. Also puzzling, if I write a temporary function renderEvents and just have it print to console, it will for each channel object and will print data passed to it properly, but still nothing renders.

Any suggestions?

Thank you!

Comment: This is... so messed up. Is there a reason that you used class component and function component together? Anyway, the `this` in `addChannel` might not reference to the class component. Please check and see what it is

Comment: @LãNgọcHải Thanks for the comment. The addChannel function is working, rendering a new channel object in my timeline, but I agree the this.child=ref parameter is the root cause of my issues, since the channels are defined dynamically. Any suggestions to test? Thanks!

Comment: It's better that you store only the data that is needed for each channel then pass them through props instead of storing the child components; with that you can directly manipulate/update the data from the parent component. If you still want to trigger the function of child component in the parent one you can use `createRef` to actually reference to the child and trigger its function. I'll make an answer if you need more clarification.

Comment: @LãNgọcHải Thanks for sticking with me. I refactored the code to have all the data in the main timeline, but now I am having a rendering issue. If my understanding is correct, the render function just returns the entire HTML tree we want to display, so adding a loop to add similar elements a controlled number of times that themselves return HTML should work, but the code above still fails to render anything from the loops. Thoughts? Thanks! (Refactored code above in main question)

Comment: If you want to call a function in the child from parent, you can try using Ref. It will help you to avoid rerendering parent component as another way is by using state or using external state manager like redux.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to return the value of `renderChannel` inside the `map`, otherwise everything would be undefined:

```
    this.state.allChannels.map((channel)=>{
        return renderChannel(this, channel)
    })
```

Comment: I figured it was something simple, thanks!